# Groovy - Split a string at last occurrence of colon

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get the image and tag name from the registry URL in my groovy script but would like to do it in a single command, is it possible ?

Something like this

```
def registry_url = 'klp.lab.eu.org:1234/repo_list/EU/node:1.1-alpine'

def (image, tag) = registry_url.split( ':' )
```

Should give me `klp.lab.eu.org:1234/repo_list/EU/node` and `1.1-alpine`

I'm aware of `tokenize` and can retrieve the tag value using `registry_url.tokenize( ':' )[-1]` but I'm not sure how to extract the image name.

Comment: String.split() returns an ArrayList so you can access each part with [0] or [1]. You cannot assign them different names in 1 line. You need to separately create variables for [0] and [1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *find operator* is easier to use than `split` for this case ('.' is greedy so you get the last colon):

```
def registry_url = 'klp.lab.eu.org:1234/repo_list/EU/node:1.1-alpine'
def (_, image, tag) = (registry_url =~ '(.*):(.*)')[0]
assert image == 'klp.lab.eu.org:1234/repo_list/EU/node'
assert tag == '1.1-alpine'
```

An alternative would be to use `lastIndexOf` (using Groovy 4 range syntax):

```
def registry_url = 'klp.lab.eu.org:1234/repo_list/EU/node:1.1-alpine'
def lastColon = registry_url.lastIndexOf(':')
def (image, tag) = registry_url.with{ [it[0..<lastColon], it[lastColon<..-1]] }
```

You can persevere with `split` if you wish:

```
def registry_url = 'klp.lab.eu.org:1234/repo_list/EU/node:1.1-alpine'
def parts = registry_url.split(':')
def (image, tag) = parts.with{ [it[0..-2].join(':'), it[-1]] }
```